# How to capture other application events in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I am developing on iPhone app, Where i want to capture the other applications event which is done for MAC. I found this through following link [How to Listen For an Application Launch Event in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304647/how-to-listen-for-an-application-launch-event-in-mac-os-x).  I need similar kind in iOS.

I tried implementing the code in iOS, but later i found that we don't have `NSWatcher` in iOS. So i tried with `NSDistributionNotification` class, but it is giving a compilation error. I checked the framework files, i found only `NSNotification.h` but No `NSDistributionNotification.h` file. Where can I find `NSDistributionNotification.h` file? How to address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Each and every App runs in its own sandbox and will not broadcast any events across the system to other Apps.

You may however invoke other Apps by using a URL scheme. Still, those will not be able to communicate back to your app unless it has also setup a URL scheme that those other Apps try to invoke. In other words, an App may be started by another App and it may also get parameters on that startup-process but that is it - no way to communicate behind the scenes other than URL scheme/s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read that all applications will send the notification to notification center. Can we read notification  center content from our application?

Comment: The NSNotificationCenter is not system-wide but limited to a single App.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this concept applies to iOS, because only one application can be running at a time, so if another application is launched, your app will be in the background, and shouldn't be running any code.

Can you explain a bit more what it is your are trying to do? There might be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, I want to capture the application's start time(launch time) and end time from my application.

Comment: @pushpa For capturing start and end (home-button pressed), you could use the described URL scheme. App A starts App B with a URL scheme while storing the startup time. App B runs and just when being sent to background, it invokes a URL scheme to hand this event back to App A. That way App A will know about both events.

Answer (score 1):

**Due to Apple's sandboxing restrictions, this is not possible on an iOS device.** The Mac has more relaxed restrictions, so I guess it is possible on there.