# Detecting when Safari has launched

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications

I'm trying to get my mac app to do something whenever Safari is launched. The obvious way to detect Safari launch is by polling for running processes. Is there a better way to do this?

I was thinking there might be some API that I could use to register callbacks on, or perhaps there's a notification center event that I can observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add yourself to `NSWorkspace`'s notification center as an observer for `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification`. When you receive the notification, examine the instance of `NSRunningApplication` it provides (object in the notification's userInfo for the key `NSWorkspaceApplicationKey`) to determine if it was Safari that was launched.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/notificationCenter) classes.

The following post might be helpful: [How to Listen For an Application Launch Event in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304647/how-to-listen-for-an-application-launch-event-in-mac-os-x)